# Working Load of 4x6 Pressure Treated

Tags: roof, load-bearing, carpentry, load, engineering

Adding a shed roof to my building that will have rafters 16" on center.

How can I find the working load of a 4x6 pressure treated beam that is supported by 4x4 posts 10' on center?  I will also add 24" knee braces to each side of posts.

Comment: Usually for beams, joining 2x together is slightly better than a single 4x.  For no snow load might be okay, but your local building department can give you much better information since they know stuff we don't about where you live.

Comment: The width and length of the shed is important also, along with the size of the rafters.  10ft centres plus knee braces I imagine this is not an 8x10ft shed.

Comment: A 2x8 or especially 2x10 will probably be cheaper and definitely will be significantly stiffer

Comment: Shed roof will be 10 wide x 20 long, was planning on 2x4 rafters due to some clearance issues with existing roof, might have to go to 12" centers for the rafters or double them up on 16" centers.  I was just curious if I have to worry about the 4x6 sagging in the middle, even with the knee braces?  No building dept. or codes in rural Montana (which is another benefit of living here).